# visual studio run .exe with argument

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

*I am new to visual studio and new to stackoverflow. This site has been very helpful in great was.*
I have made a button to run a .exe and it world well. I am now trying to run that .exe with arguments and dont know how. I normal run it with a .bat file but would like to switch it over to .exe.

Here is the .bat with the arguments i normally run.

```
program.exe -o www.website.com -u user -p password
```

Here is the visual studio button i have made

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("E:\test\program.exe")
    End Sub
End Class
```

How do I run the .exe with those arguments. Thank you for you time and help.

Answer (score 7):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload that takes two parameters, the second one is the arguments list that you want to pass to your process.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("E:\test\program.exe", "-o www.website.com -u user -p password")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You could also look at the overload that takes a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allow to fine tune the environment in which you start the required process

The receiving application can get access to the parameters passed using code similar to this one

```
For Each pp in My.Application.CommandLineArgs
     MessageBox.Show(pp)
Next
```

Comment: Sorry for jumping in with a question, but can you please write how do you 'read' those parameters in newly started .exe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parameters are passed to your target program and you could retrieve them with `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` or you can modify your Main function to read them directly from there. Try to search for `Reading Command Line arguments in VB.NET` and you will find many useful links

Comment: So, basically you are passing arguments as array and then parse them, right?

Comment: No, I don't parse anything, they are automatically added to the CommandLineArgs array. Added example for the receiving app

Comment: But in which way does that newly started .exe knows how many arguments I've sent? Since there is no delimiters or anything else.

Comment: [This is a link to MSDN for CommandLineArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2d603cy(v=vs.90).aspx) The CommandLineArgs is a string collection. It is prepared by the Net Framework for you and the Count property is present as usual. Just make a little ConsoleApplication and test at your leasure.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your kind help. I already gave you +1!

Comment: I would definetly mark your post as answer, but I didn't opened this question, another guy did, I just jumped in with a new question related to first one :)